# ShellExecuteEx silently fails in 64-bit call to hidden file

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a 64-bit console app that just wants to open a file. File's hidden attribute is set (the file is hidden). The code below fails only on some machines. `ShellExecuteEx` would actually return `TRUE`, but the .txt file would not open in Notepad, and `hProcess` member of `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure remains zero after the call.

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = {0};
sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
sei.hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
sei.lpVerb = _T("open");
sei.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
sei.lpFile = _T("C:\\some\\existing\\file.txt");

BOOL bRC = ShellExecuteEx(&sei);

MessageBox(GetConsoleWindow(), sei.lpFile, sei.lpVerb, MB_OK);
```

Call to `MessageBox` is there just so that there's enough time for `ShellExecuteEx` to do its magic. The .txt file will open in Notepad if at least one of the following conditions is met:

- .txt file is not hidden
- the calling process is 32-bit, instead of 64-bit
- the machine is some other (can't figure out what is the difference between machines, but the file is not open in at least one Vista and one Windows 8.1)
- `lpVerb` is `nullptr`, `"openas"` or `"properties"` (which will of course just show file's properties), instead of `"open"`, `"edit"`, or even `"runas"` (for .exe instead of .txt)

What is going on here? Windows Explorer properly opens the hidden file, because it uses null verb, but I have to use the verb ("runas" actually, but please don't be distracted by this info). It should work with "open" as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Step 1, perform error checking. What value has `bRC`? If it is false, call `GetLastError`. As stated in the documentation.

Comment: Fixed backslashes. Please note that the code runs okay if file is not hidden.

Comment: Please. Don't. Post. Fake. Code!

Comment: Instead of using `"open"` as the verb try `nullptr` and see if it helps - that way you get the default double-click action no matter what `"open"` has been assigned as.

Comment: P.S. I don't think 64 bit has anything to do with whatever your problem is.

Comment: Perhaps the difference between machines is whether or not the user has configured Explorer to show hidden files?

Comment: @Harry I wish it would be that easy. No, Explorer is set to show hidden files on all machines.

Comment: You want to understand what's going wrong and yet you won't perform error checking. How committed are you to solving this problem?

Comment: @David, sorry, I thought you weren't serious the first time. Of course there's error checking. It's removed here for clarity. I did mention from the start that `ShellExecuteEx` actually returns `TRUE` even when the file is not open, and also `hProcess` is zero. What more could I put in the question?

Comment: Ok. I can see the part of the question where you say that `SEE` returns `TRUE`. I didn't cotton on to that before. Sorry.

Comment: An `hProcess` of zero is normal when Windows asks an existing process to open the file.  Have you tried using Process Monitor (available for download from the MS web site) to see what's happening inside Explorer?  Comparing a working machine to a non-working one might give you some useful clues.

Comment: Also have you checked that the directory containing the file is otherwise completely empty?  No other hidden and/or system files or subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in one Explorer extension. Ironically (but unsurprisingly) it was our own extension. If the extension is unregistered the problem is gone, and `ShellExecute` works again for all verbs.